# display contents in input

Tags: php

I have anchor tag and input tag

```
<a href="example.com">Go to Example.com</a>
```

and

```
&lt;a href="example.com"&gt;Go to Example.com&lt;/a&gt;
```

Now I need to display above text in input box

```
<input type="text" value="<a href="example.com">Go to Example.com</a>">
```

But it's not working, How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to see the link in the text box OR want to see it as <a href="example.com">Go to Example.com</a> in the text box?

Comment: @enam: I need to see it as <a href="example.com">Go to Example.com</a> in the text box

Comment: doesn't my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change quotes to html entities:

```
&quot;

<input type="text" value="<a href=&quot;example.com&quot;>Go to Example.com</a>">
```

Comment: didn't get you, please explain

Comment: @I-M-JM: you have to replace `"` char to according html entity `&quot;` within `value=""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="<a href=&quot;example.com&quot;>Go to Example.com</a>">
```